New line character within data giving issues while loading using IICS
we have a pipe delimited file qualified by double quotes. Some columns have free text data with newline and special characters(" representing inches) in it. When we try to ingest this data in IICS, the text columns with newline reads as separate rows in IICS. How can we replace newline within the text columns with space to fix this issue.
Tried the below gawk command but this is not fixing the issues
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 {gsub(/[/\n]/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' output2.csv > output3.csv

ROW1: this scenario is not fixed with the above gawk command - was able to fix after manually escaping the inches symbol inside the data. Is there a way to escape all the inches symbol using script?
"col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"2002-04-09 00:00:00"|"True"|"2023 - (1) FA L-shape desk (left-handed)
2023 - (1) 29" credenza for BOA, (1) custom 66" BOA A2 workstation with HA bridge (left-handed)
2023 - (1) 42" round table
2023 - (5) Rein guest chairs in hashtag fabric"|"5"

Output when I executed the gawk, the record was in a single line :
"2002-04-09 00:00:00"|"True"|"2023 - (1) FA L-shape desk (left-handed)2023 - (1) 29"" credenza for BOA, (1) custom 66"" BOA A2 workstation with HA bridge (left-handed)2023 - (1) 42"" round table2023 - (5) Rein guest chairs in hashtag fabric|"5"
ROW2: this scenario is not fixed with the above gawk command - is the hypen or any special character like (:) causing issue here?
"col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"2020-06-30 00:00:00"|"False"|"STANDARD:
2008 1-Endura FA Workstation
2008 1-Endura BOA Workstation with Lateral File Cabinet
2021 2-Zonal Task Chairs "|"4"

Output : no change
expected the output to be in a single row with new line characters replaced

I've applied what I think is the correct formatting for your sample inputs - please edit as needed; in the meantime, please also update the question with a) the (wrong) output generated by your code and b) the (correct) expected output, making sure these new data sets correspond to the provided sample inputs

can the pipe character show up in the actual data or is it 100% guaranteed to only show up as a field delimiter?

@markp-fuso - most of the columns are free text - so there is a chance for the | pipe delimiter to be present in actual data. Unfortunately IICS does not support multicharacter delimiter

are all fields guaranteed to be wrapped in double quotes?

for the first sample input can you confirm the last line - fabric|"5" - is supposed to be missing a double quote before the pipe; or should there be a double quote before the pipe like: frabric"|"5"?

can any of the fields be blank and if so would they still be wrapped in double quotes? for example, for a blank field would we see || or |""|?

@markp-fuso - yes all fields are guaranteed to be double quoted. Even though they are blank they will wrapped in double quoted.      Sorry you are right, I missed a " - typo error

If you have free-text in a column, the only sure way to ensure problem-free load of such text is to use unique characters for delimiters during creation of this file. Just remember that you need two delimiters - for columns, and for records.
You can use any characters with ASCII code less than 0x20 (which is space character). It is safe to assume that these characters will not appear in a normal text field.
My favorites are \t and \v, also known as Tabulation (\x09) and Vertical tabulation (\x0b). They are not visible on a screen, but works perfectly for delimited file.
If the file is not created by you - the best way you have is to complain to whoever creates it and demand from them to use proper (even though slightly unusual) delimiters.
If it is not possible to recreate the file with different delimiters - all you can do is to write a special program, which would make a guess on where the free-text field is starting/ending.
Something like
   if ( /^"(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)"\|"(false|true)"\|(.*)/ ) {
      $col1 = $1;
      $col2 = $2;
      $col3 = $3;
      $in_free_text = 1;
   } elsif ( /(.*)\|"(\d)"$/ ) {
      $col3 .= $1;
      $col4 = $2;
      $in_free_text = 1;
   } else {
      if ( $in_free_text = 1 ) {
         $col3 .= $_;
      }
   }

Probably, such script will help with data. But it can require a lot of tweaking and massaging to work properly.
It would be much easier and more reliable to ask for a file with better delimiters.

No standard POSIX tool will accept \d as shorthand for [[:digit:]] - you should say in your question which tool you expect that code to work in (and preferably show a complete script using it).

Assumptions/understandings:

all fields are wrapped in double quotes
blank fields will show up in the file as ""
the pipe (|) may show up in the data
the double quote (") may show up in the data
fields may contain embedded linefeeds
an embedded linefeed is to be converted to a single space
the header row (FNR==1) does not contain any embedded linefeeds
[key assumption] the 3-character string "|" only shows up as a field delimiter
a field may start with a newline character; in this case a) the end of the line will end with "|" and b) the last field ($NF) will not end in a double quote)

Extending OP's sample input to include additional test cases:
$ cat output2.csv
"col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"2002-04-09 00:00:00"|"True"|"2023 - (1) FA L-shape desk (left-handed)
2023 - (1) 29" credenza for BOA, (1) custom 66" BOA A2 workstation with HA bridge (left-handed)
2023 - (1) 42" round table
2023 - (5) Rein guest chairs in hashtag fabric"|"5"
"2020-06-30 00:00:00"|"False"|"STANDARD:
2008 1-Endura FA Workstation
2008 1-Endura BOA Workstation with Lateral File Cabinet
2021 2-Zonal Task Chairs "|"4"
"field1"|"field2"|"field3"|"
field4"
"col1"|"col2"|"
col3"|"col4"
"new1"|"new2"|"new3"|""
"last1"|"last2"|"
"|"last4"

One awk idea:
awk '
BEGIN  { FS = "\"[|]\""                                     # input field delimiter is the 3-character string: "|"  (includes the double quotes)
         dq = "\""                                          # variable to hold a single instance of a literal double quote
       }

FNR==1 { maxNF = NF }                                       # header row tells us the max number of fields in a line

       { lastchar = substr($NF,length($NF))                 # obtain last character of last field

          if (NF == maxNF && lastchar == dq) {              # if line has maxNF fields and last character is a double quote then ...
              print $0                                      # print current line and ...
              next                                          # skip to next line of  input
          }
          else {
              currNF += (lastchar == dq ? NF : (NF-1) )     # sum up the number of fields to this point

              if (currNF >= maxNF) { print $0; currNF=0 }   # if we now have maxNF fields then print this line (terminating previous printf calls) and reset currNF counter
              else                 printf "%s", $0          # otherwise printf current line to stdout but without a trailing linefeed, ie, leave cursot at end of current line
          }
       }
' output2.csv

This generates:
"col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"2002-04-09 00:00:00"|"True"|"2023 - (1) FA L-shape desk (left-handed)2023 - (1) 29" credenza for BOA, (1) custom 66" BOA A2 workstation with HA bridge (left-handed)2023 - (1) 42" round table2023 - (5) Rein guest chairs in hashtag fabric"|"5"
"2020-06-30 00:00:00"|"False"|"STANDARD:2008 1-Endura FA Workstation2008 1-Endura BOA Workstation with Lateral File Cabinet2021 2-Zonal Task Chairs "|"4"
"field1"|"field2"|"field3"|"field4"
"col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"new1"|"new2"|"new3"|""
"last1"|"last2"|""|"last4"

